# Solarwinds could be manipulated for automation

Tags: server-monitoring, solarwinds-orion

How we could manipulate Solarwinds that would be useful for an automated deploy. This could be a command line interface or an API or anything else that would let us disabled and re-enable Solarwinds monitors without human intervention. More detail will be added as becomes known

Use the SolarWinds API to add monitor disable and re-enable into the deployment script

Please assist with a script. Thanks

Maybe put the script in deploy.target

Amit

Answer (score 5):

SolarWinds Orion has an SDK you can use to manage and unmanage (disable and reenable monitoring for) nodes. The download link is in this post: http://thwack.solarwinds.com/thread/39001. The SDK contains documentation that describes how to programmatically/remotely invoke these commands.